# Place uiview proportionally to the height, how?

Tags: ios, swift3

I´m trying to make an app that will look close to identical for every iPhone device? Let's say that I want to place a UIView with the distance from the top according to (view.bounds.height * (2/5)). Right now I´m edit the constraints through the code to make it work but it feels like i missing some great autolayout feature?

Which is the best way to handle this?

Thanks on forehand

Comment: You can maintain your `UIView`'s Aspect Ratio (one of the Auto Layout constraints), in order to make your view look close to identical for every iPhone device.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apple constrain for solve this one

[Follow this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRDTj.jpg)

step 1:
make uiview

step 2:
open constrain

step 3: 
add two constrain, left and right constrain

step 4:
use control + drag from uiview to your superview diagonally

step 5:
click to your view controller, check the constrain, see the right panel, there are your constrain, click edit on equal height to superview

step 6:
add your multiplier: 2/5 is 0.4

step 7:
add your multiplier too in "align center Y" constrain with same multiplier

step 8:
and finish, your uiview will be 40 percent to superview in every device

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UIView on top of the parent set its height to be equal to 0.4 of the parent view with equals heights constraint and bind it top,left and right with zero constaint. Then add the view you want underneat that one and put a top constraint to the previous one equal to 0. This will place your desiered view always with a top equal to 2/5 of the parent view's height.